# initializing checkbox in JS and at the click of it should give row data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Need to add  checkbox in js .

[The code for html and js is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANZD0.png)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // -- -- -- -- -- -- --Need to add a check box here which will give me yhe row data once i click it-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- - 
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].ID + "</td>";
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].Topic + "</td>";
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].Description + "</td>";
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].EmployeeName + "</td>";
}
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Post code HERE, not pictures of code

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
--------------Need to add a check box here which will give me yhe row data once i click it-------------------
               tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].ID + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].Topic + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].Description + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].EmployeeName + "</td>";
            }

Comment: UPDATE THE QUESTION, Remove the picture and Format the code. Click edit, then `[<>]` and produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. row code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
let data=[
{id:1,topic:".Net Core",description:".Net core Desc" },
{id:2,topic:"C#",description:"C# Desc" },
{id:3,topic:"Javascript",description:"Javascript Desc" }
]

var tableBody="";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
var tr="<tr>";
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>";
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].topic + "</td>";
  tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].description + "</td>";
  tr = tr + "<td><input type='checkbox' onClick='fnDataReturn("+JSON.stringify(data[i])+")'/></td>";
  tr=tr+"</tr>";
  tableBody=tableBody+tr;
} 
  $("#table tbody").append(tableBody)
});

function fnDataReturn(data){
console.log("succes",data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<thead>
<th>CIP Id</th>
<th>Topic</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Checkbox</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to have inline event handlers. ESPECIALLY not when you have jQuery to help

Comment: If you look at the source code (image) there is a document-ready function available that's why I have used it understandable for him. Thanks @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

You need to have valid HTML. You need ID on the tbody

Then you can do this (uncomment the getJSON code to get the data from server)

```js
// test data
const data = [
  { ID: 1, Topic: "Topic 1", Description: "Description 1", EmployeeName: "Employee 1" },
  { ID: 2, Topic: "Topic 2", Description: "Description 2", EmployeeName: "Employee 2" },
  { ID: 3, Topic: "Topic 3", Description: "Description 3", EmployeeName: "Employee 3" },
  { ID: 4, Topic: "Topic 4", Description: "Description 4", EmployeeName: "Employee 4" },
];
const url = "htps://....";
$(function() {
  // $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
  const html = data.map(
    item => `<tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" class="show">${item.ID}</td>
               <td>${item.Topic}</td>
               <td>${item.Description}</td>
               <td>${item.EmployeeName}</td>
             </tr>`).join("");
  $("#tbldemo").html(html).show();
  // }); // end of getJSON

  // Delegation can handle dynamic tbody content

  $("#tbldemo").on("click", ".show", function() {
    const data = $(this).closest("tr")
      .find("td")
      .map(function() {
        return this.textContent
      })
      .get();
    console.log(data.join(", "))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CIP Id</th>
      <th>Topic</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Employee name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbldemo"></tbody>
</table>
```